# Pagination Table only do not show data on some pages

Tags: php

My table shows 5 rows and uses pagination to go to the other datas.  my problem is, my table doesn't show the other data unless the total rows is divisible by 5

```
$page=$_GET["page"];

        if ($page=="" || $page=="1") {
                $page1=0;     
        }
        else {
            $page1=($page*5)-5;
        }

    $sql = "SELECT * from project order by province ASC LIMIT $page1,5";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

    $sql2 = "SELECT * from project ";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
    $pagen = mysqli_num_rows($res);

    $a = $pagen/5;
    /* echo ceil($a);*/


    ?>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by _"the other data"_? I would also recommend that you use `SELECT count(*) as total FROM project` and get the value of `total` in your second query instead of actually selecting all the rows.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the table only shows data from rows divisible by 5, 

example, I have 13 rows, my table shows 10 rows bc its divisible by 5,  the other 3 rows do not show up

Comment: If you set `?page=3` in the URL, you don't see the last three? Please show us all the relevant code (how you loop out the result and create your pagination buttons). The above code should at least fetch the rows. However, I would change the first `if` to: `$page = intval($page) < 2 ? 0 : (($page * 5) - 5);`. Currently, if you pass `?page=foo`, you would get an unexpected behavior (and a "non-numeric" warning in PHP 7.1).

Comment: <div class="pagination">
    <?php 
 for ($b=1; $b<=$a; $b++) { 
  ?><a href="mainProject.php?page=<?php echo $b;?>"><?php echo $b," "?> </a> <?php
 }
?>
</div>   --------the 'a' used in the for is in the post

Comment: Please edit your question to include _all_ relevant code instead of posting it in comments. And you should definitely use ceil: `$a = ceil($pagen / 5);`.

Comment: $a = ceil($pagen / 5); ceil worked for me, now it displays now thank you thank you :)  @MagnusEriksson